# Android - Get recyclerview clicked item's SQLite object data

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I want to delete a clicked item of a RecyclerView where the items consist of data from SQLite.

I've successfully detected a clicked item for the RecyclerView (followed a tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69C1ljfDvl0&t=487s) but cannot get the item's data to be deleted by a delete method I already created.
Here is the delete method:

```java
public boolean deleteOne(OneTimeActivityModel oneTimeActivityModel){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String queryString = "DELETE FROM " + ONE_TIME_ACTIVITY_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ACTIVITY_NAME + " = " + oneTimeModel.getId();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The method works in ListView because in ListView I can use .getItemAtPosition(position) when the item is clicked and get the model of the item to be sent to the method.

Here is the code where the item is clicked:

```java
@Override
    public void onNoteClick(int position) {
        OneTimeDatabaseHelper oneTimeDatabaseHelper = new OneTimeDatabaseHelper(ListActivity.this);
        OneTimeActivityModel clickedActivity; // How to make this variable become the model of the clicked item

        // in ListView I can use this following line
        // OneTimeActivityModel clickedActivity = (OneTimeActivityModel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        oneTimeDatabaseHelper.deleteOne(clickedActivity); //To be sent to the delete method

    }
```

It seems that I need to store the item in the "oneTimeDatabaseHelper" variable to be sent to the method.

How do I get the datas of the clicked item in RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe getting the whole model is not necessary in this case. Rather than taking the whole `OneTimeActivityModel` as an argument, you can take just the ID or any unique identifiers in order to be used as the deletion criteria in the `WHERE` SQL clause.

It can be rewritten like this:

```java
public boolean deleteOne(String oneTimeID){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String queryString = "DELETE FROM " + ONE_TIME_ACTIVITY_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ACTIVITY_NAME + " = " + "'" + oneTimeID + "'";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

As for the second question, you can take the ID of the currently clicked item, and then you pass that corresponding ID into `oneTimeDatabaseHelper.deleteOne`.  To provide a basis to rely on:

```java
@Override
    public void onNoteClick(int position) {
        OneTimeDatabaseHelper oneTimeDatabaseHelper = new OneTimeDatabaseHelper(ListActivity.this);
        OneTimeActivityModel clickedActivity = dataSource.get(position);
        oneTimeDatabaseHelper.deleteOne(clickedActivity.getID());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

---

Despite my answer, if I were you, I would inject the model at the `onBindViewHolder` method, and process each and every model at the `ViewHolder` level instead of brute-forcing via `onClick` in the general adapter class. For example:

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position, OneTimeActivityModel model) {
    holder.bindObject(model);
}
```

While in the `ViewHolder`, you'll do something like:

```java
// omitted for brevity
public void bindObject(OneTimeActivityModel model) {
    view.setOnClickListener(...) // do whatever you want here.
}
```

One advantage of my approach over yours is that the models are strongly typed and you do not have to call `notifyDataSetChanged` and/or get your data source like that (using `position` while you can just fetch it from a holder).

Comment: Thanks! It works when I change the parameter not to the model but to the string of the column. Bless you sir.